# POST Request with a 302 redirect never gets to its destination

Tags: apache2, magento

For example, this request in the access_log:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) - - [31/Jan/2019:16:19:24 +0100] "POST /ppt/index/result/id/2000000169/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Java/1.7.0"
```

How come that it looks like it never gets to the application. I have put some logs in the application but it never gets fired. Same URL but with a GET request it goes through

So, what could it be? Could apache just negate POST resquests because of some configuration?

Comment: Apache has no problem with redirects as a result of a `POST`. Add debugging code to the client, or if you use http, watch the network traffic.

Comment: What does the Java/1.7.0 at the end means? And the 302 means that it got temporary redirect right?

Comment: The "Java/1.7.0" should be the user agent sent by the client, and 302 the status code of the request. Maybe the Java client doesn't like the 302 in response to a POST request.